# Postgres UPSERT and id SERIAL issue

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

CREATE TABLE:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tests (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, "name" VARCHAR);
```

UPSERT:

```sql
INSERT INTO tests (id, "name") 
VALUES (?, ?)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
SET "name" = EXCLUDED."name";
```

The problem is that it never executes the UPDATE part because SERIAL type resolves all conflicts - it just inserts existing records as new records with new ids (nextval) instead of updating them.

I am trying to implement a "Save All Records" function. It should update existing records and insert new ones if they do not exist.

The algorithm I imagined:

```java
connection.setAutoCommit(false);

for (Test test : tests)
{
    statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tests (id, \"name\") VALUES (?, ?) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE  SET \"name\" = EXCLUDED.\"name\";");
    statement.setInt(1, test.getId());
    statement.setString(2, test.getName());
    statement.execute();
}

connection.commit();
```

Comment: Why are you inserting into a `serial` value?  I don't fully understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have a table where id's are autoincremented. I pull the table from DB into the java collection. Then I display this local collection via `TableView`. Rows may be updated, inserted and deleted locally. Once I've finished with my modification, I need to save the results - update records inside the DB based on the local copy.

Comment: You should be using the serial id for updates and deletes.  You should leave the `id` out of the query for `insert`s.

Comment: You can try with jdbc batch update